# More specific/stronger MemberExpression for compile-time checking?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, dsl, roslyn

Consider the GetPropertyName method in the code sample below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SampleApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var name = GetPropertyName<Box, string>(b => b.Position);

            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        private static string GetPropertyName<T, TP>(Expression<Func<T, TP>> exp)
        {
            var memberExpression = exp.Body as MemberExpression;

            return memberExpression == null ? null : memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }
    }

    public class Box
    {
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way of making that method's parameter so specific that it wouldn't compile unless a get+set property is being passed? Something like this:

```
private static string GetPropertyName<T, TP>(PropertyExpression<T, TP>> exp) {}
```

... to fix situations like this at compile time:

```
var name = GetPropertyName<Box, string>(b => "AAA");
```

PS: will Roslyn fix this situation?

PPS: context: implementing a strict internal DSL.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way of making that method's parameter so specific that it wouldn't compile unless a get+set property is being passed?

No. It's just a lambda expression. There are restrictions about what kind of lambda expressions can be converted into expression trees, but nothing that says it's just got to be a property.

> PS: will Roslyn fix this situation?

Well, you could add a code diagnostic to check this... but better, you could use `nameof` in C# 6 to avoid having a `GetPropertyName` method at all.

Comment: Sorry, I have added a clarification that my objective is building a strict internal DSL, that method is just a minimal sample.

Comment: @Den: Well that doesn't really give us much more context, to be honest - that doesn't tell us how you're using `GetPropertyName`, or why you think `nameof` wouldn't be a suitable alternative.

Comment: It's EF/NHibernate style of DSL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900902/definition-of-the-nhibernate-mapping-by-code-ef-code-first-pattern

I think Roslyn is my only option.

Comment: @Den: Nope, that still hasn't given me *nearly* enough context to see why you'd reject using `nameof`, or how you intend to use Roslyn. I can't really help any further without more context.